# Why do I have now ESP spanish options?

Tags: input-languages

I have noticed that now my Windows 10 have 2 different ESP languages although there is only 1 configured.

[image]

[image]

Not sure if this is related to an update as I did not change anything on the configuration and I always had only 2 options ENG an ESP.

Comment: Most likely neither we can give you the reason. Try to delete the one you don't need, then check whether it comes back. If yes, post when.

Comment: In Settings, click on Español (Perú), then on Options. What do you have under Keyboards? If you have more than one, click the unwanted one and then click Remove.

Comment: I deleted the Español (Perú) and now I have one ENG and one ESP that says Spain, International. In Languages preferences there is only one Language English with only one keyboard QWERTY